# Is set membership operation defined for two elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Naive Set Theory by P.R. Halmos and i stumbled across this thing in the second chapter:

```
  not(x∈x)
```

with the apparent meaning that x is an element of a set. What does this mean? If set membership operation is only defined for (element, set) pairs, can it be defined also for two elements?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a setup for Russell's Paradox. For the $\in$ to make sense, $x$ must be both a set and an element of a set. So it is saying that

> set $x$ is not an element of itself.

This would be true of the set of elephants, but not of the set $x=\{x\}$.

Now, the problem arises if we try to create the set of $x$'s satisfying that definition: the **set of all sets which aren't elements of themselves.** let's call that set $X$.

Is $X$ an element of itself? If so, then it can't be an element of itself, because it must satisfy the definition of an $x$. But if it isn't an element of itself it *satisfies* the definition, making it an element of itself . . .

The contradiction means that $X$ can't exist—which also demolishes the idea that there can be a set of all sets.

And that's basically why naive set theory is so called—it hasn't been formulated to prevent contradictions like Russell's Paradox arising.

Answer (score 1):

To extend beyond what others have said, in many axiomatizations of set theory there are no objects *but* sets; membership is a relation which takes two sets, not which takes an 'element' of a set - all the elements of sets are themselves sets. In this sort of theory, one usually 'boostraps'; we have an axiom saying that the empty set $\emptyset = \{\}$ is a set; then we have an axiom saying that for each set $A$ we can form the set $\{A\}$ which has $A$ as its only member; this immediately gives us infinitely many sets $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\},\ldots$ — and further axioms (such as the union axiom, etc.) let us make still more sets out of these, and so on and so forth.

Comment: And $x=\{x\}$ instantly gets infinitely deeply nested inside itself . . .

Answer (score 1):

This statement (no set is an element of itself) follows from what's usually known as the Axiom of Foundation:$$\forall x \neq \emptyset \exists y \in x \text{ with } y \cap x = \emptyset.$$

To imagine a counterexample, consider $y = \{\{\{\cdots x \cdots\}\}\}.$  The existence of pathological sets of this nature is ruled out by the Axiom of Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Elements of sets may well be sets. (For example, the sets of all subsets of some set is clearly a set of sets.) So in principle some set $x$ might be an element of itself. However, the assertion you cited claims that this can actually never happen: no set is an element of itself.

Comment: In isolation it doesn't assert that for every set—just for whichever one $x$ represents. There's no "for all $x$" mentioned.